# Vim Highlight Search in vimrc

Tags: vim

The following code works in the terminal

```
hi Search ctermfg=Red ctermbg=White cterm=NONE
```

As soon as it is added to vimrc, saved, and sourced the search is not highlited. It is highlited in the default color but not in the new color mentioned.

Any tips of why that is happening?

Comment: Did you put it before a line that sets the colorscheme?

Comment: Yes I did! I moved it after the colorscheme and works as expected. Do you want to add your comment as an answer so that I can give you the "credit"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put your `hi` command before a `colorscheme` command in your vimrc, the loaded colorscheme is probably overwriting your highlight with one of its own. Try moving it to after the colorscheme.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this in your `.vimrc`.

`hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=blue`

looks great in mobaxter or any black background terminal

Answer (score 0):

Your custom highlight will be reset if you change colorscheme.
In that case you may use `autocmd` to achieve that like:
`autocmd ColorScheme * hi Search ctermfg=Red ctermbg=White cterm=NONE`